# App crashing - Extending CursorAdapter

Tags: android

Working on my first Android app and facing a challenge.
I am pulling calls from CallLog contentprovider and displaying using a cursor adapter.
I have overriden bindView and newView. I am not using SimpleCursorAdapter as I need to format the date. I am new to Android so prone to silly mistakes. :)
I am calling this cursorAdapter in the main Activity using this code.

```
startManagingCursor(calls);
adapter = new CallsAdapter(this, calls);
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

---

```
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    displayDate(view, date);
}

private void displayDate(View view, String strDate) {
    final long timestamp = Long.parseLong(strDate);
    final String formattedDate = DATEFORMAT.format(new Date(timestamp));
    final TextView t = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.date_text);
    t.setText(formattedDate);
}

public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    final View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.scratch_layout2, parent, false);
    return view;
}
```

---

But my app crashes before it starts.

Edited - Heres the error log.

```
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12885): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
02-09 06:05:28.281: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12885): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.amannain.android.missedcalls/com.amannain.android.missedcalls.MissedCallsActivity}: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 6
02-09 06:05:28.281: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12885):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2268)
02-09 06:05:28.281: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12885):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2284)
02-09 06:05:28.281: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12885):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:112)
02-09 06:05:28.281: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12885):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1692)
02-09 06:05:28.281: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12885):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-09 06:05:28.281: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12885):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-09 06:05:28.281: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12885):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3948)
02-09 06:05:28.281: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12885):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-09 06:05:28.281: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12885):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
02-09 06:05:28.281: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12885):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:782)
02-09 06:05:28.281: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12885):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:540)
02-09 06:05:28.281: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12885):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-09 06:05:28.281: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12885): Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 6
02-09 06:05:28.281: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12885):     at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:580)
02-09 06:05:28.281: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12885):     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:172)
02-09 06:05:28.281: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12885):     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:41)
02-09 06:05:28.281: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12885):     at android.database.CursorWrapper.getString(CursorWrapper.java:135)
02-09 06:05:28.281: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12885):     at com.amannain.android.missedcalls.MissedCallsAdapter.<init>(MissedCallsAdapter.java:24)
02-09 06:05:28.281: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12885):     at com.amannain.android.missedcalls.MissedCallsActivity.onCreate(MissedCallsActivity.java:27)
02-09 06:05:28.281: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12885):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1123)
02-09 06:05:28.281: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12885):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2231)
02-09 06:05:28.281: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12885):     ... 11 more
```

Regards,
Aman

Comment: Please define "crashing". If you are getting an exception in LogCat please add it to your question.

Comment: What error do you get in your console/logcat/debugger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `MissedCallsAdapter` you seem to call the cursor in the constructor long before the adapter is really initialized

```
Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 6
at android.database.CursorWrapper.getString(CursorWrapper.java:135) 
at com.amannain.android.missedcalls.MissedCallsAdapter.<init>(MissedCallsAdapter.java:24)
at com.amannain.android.missedcalls.MissedCallsActivity.onCreate(MissedCallsActivity.java:27)
```

Check line 24 of your adapter code. Or rather line 27 where this call to the constructor happens in `onCreate`.

Comment: Thanks for editing my error log and pointing towards the problem. I was making a silly mistake of initialing my variables in the construct method of cursor adapter. Its working now. :)